Interest rate hedging under Vasicek model
Let's consider the case of a bank that receive of 1,000,000$ from a customer and decides to invest that amount between a long term Treasury bond and an overnight deposit (alternatively, it could invest in a short term bond). In front of that strategy, the customer may receive an annuity , let's say every 6 months for 30 years.
If the term structure of interest rate is assumed to be flat over time, the bank could decide how much of the wealth to be invested time by time in the long term bond according to an easy rule:
$x_t = \frac{D_A}{D_L}$
where $x_t$ is the relative weight invested in the treasury bond, $D_A$ is its modified duration and, assuming that the duration of the overnight deposit is zero, $D_L$ is the duration of the liability, i.e. of the
annuity that is going to be paid to the customer in front of the initial deposit.
In this way, the bank can be immunized from (small and parallel) movements of the interest rate.
The problem occurs when the interest rate term structure is assumed to be no longer flat, but time varying in a stochastic fashion. In particular, the assumption is that the Vasicek is the data generating process and that we know for sure the right parameters.
Under this model, the price of a ZCB available at time t with maturity T is
$Z(t,T) = \exp{\left(A(t,T) - B(t,T)r_t\right)}$
where $r_t$ is the instantaneous spot rate observed at time $t$ which drives the whole term structure.
In a case like that, how can the bank hedge from interest rate risk? What should be the concept of duration to be used? And how can it compute the weights at the beginning of each period, assuming that the interest rate term structure path is known in advance (not stochastic) ?
My idea was to use a different concept of duration, like the spot rate duration that can be analytically computed as:
$D_Z(\tau) = -\frac{1}{Z} \frac{\partial Z}{\partial r} = B(\tau) = \frac{1}{\gamma} \left( 1 - e^{-\gamma \times \tau} \right)$
where $\tau$ represents the time to maturity.
